# Rails rescue specific error and send to rollbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollbar

In my call method I want to expire all offers but, to do so, I have catch two specific errors (validations and possible AASM) and rescue from them. Both of them should be sended to Rollbar.

```
def call
  all_to_expire.each do |offer|
    offer.expire!(actor: self)
  rescue StandardError => e
    Rollbar.error(e)
  end
end
```

Method above doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if Ruby is understanding this kind of block structure. I would rewrite it as:

```
def call
  all_to_expire.each do |offer|
    begin
      offer.expire!(actor: self)
    rescue AASM::InvalidTransition, ActiveModel::ValidationError => e
      Rollbar.error(e)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm looking good but I think instead of `StandardError` it should be `ActiveModel::ValidationError` (because I want to rescue from validation) and something more to skip AASM error (don't know what exactly, error that it was not possible to move to the new state - can't find how to do so).

Comment: @mr_muscle I updated my answer with more the precise error types.